# Pass a variable from Ajax to VB Script Function in classic ASP

Tags: ajax, vbscript, parameters, asp-classic, parameter-passing

I have a classic ASP code and I would like to pass a variable `terms` from Ajax to VB Script Function. I tried the below code but it is not working.

This is my first time write code using ajax. So I am aware that this is very basic.. But I cannot find out where is wrong. Could anyone help me out, please?

```
<script type="text/Javascript">        
    $(document).ready( function(){  
var availableCode = new Array();            

function customFilter(terms) {
                $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Test.asp",   // This asp file name itself
                 data: {"strUserInput": '"' + $("#terms").val() + '"'  },
                 cache: false,
                 success: function() { 
                        alert ("returned from server side");
                 }
             });

            <%
            Dim idxJs
            for idxJs = 0 to 19 
            %>
                availableCode[<%=idxJs %>] = unescape('<%= Escape(codeList(idxJs)) %>');

            <% next %>

                return availableCode;
            };

            $( "#frmBillCode" ).autocomplete({
              multiple: true,
              mustMatch: false,
              minLength: 4,
              delay: 100,
              search: function (event,ui) {
                window.pageIndex = 0;
                },
              source: function (request, response) {
                response(customFilter(request.term));
              }
            });
        } );
</script>   

<%
    Dim strUserInput
    strUserInput = Request.Form("strUserInput")
    Document.write(strUserInput)
%>
```

Comment: You can't. JavaScript runs client-side and VB runs server-side.

Comment: you cannot call server side code directly from client side, you need to use ajax

Comment: @dave  Thank you for your prompt response. I am afraid but I am a web development beginner. Would you mind providing me some references?

Comment: @Ilya Bursov I could not tag multiple people in the above comment. It would be appreciated if I could refer something.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: server side code is always executed BEFORE anything on the client side gets executed, so you'll need to send the data back to the server somehow, either through a form submission, or ajax, as previously suggested. I would google "jquery ajax" to start getting yourself familiar with it.

Comment: @Josh Montgomery I am new to web development so I really appreciate your advise how I can find resources.

Comment: i guess the first thing I would ask you is now, with the different responses you got, WHY your code doesn't work? do you understand how asp pages work? it's ok if you don't, we just need a better sense of what level you're at. being "new" to web dev can mean a lot of different things to a lot of different people, so clarity would help.

Comment: @Josh Montgomery Thank you for trying to help me out. I got a better idea how ASP works now. Now I understand that it does not work because I was trying to pass client side variable to server side. I have coding experience as a desktop/mainframe/database application developer for years so programming logic is fine with me but I need to learn syntax differences and interactions among different languages inside of one piece of ASP page. Right now I am trying to learn what can be compatible among these languages inside of ASP and what cannot be implemented. Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this logic did not work in our system, I changed to use lazy loading and now it is working upon our business requirements. Thank you again for advice, everyone.

Answer (score 2):

it's probably not working because of the alert statement, which is invalid. you're trying to alert a string w/out the quotes! if you wanted to do what you were trying (in this case, the alert is useless because it's after the ajax call and wouldn't have access to the new value stored in strUserInput), it would need quotes around it:

```
alert('<%=strUserInput%>');
```

but again, you don't need it, I just wanted to explain why you were potentially failing.

let's try this:

```
<%
    Dim strUserInput
    strUserInput = Request.Form("strUserInput")
    if strUserInput <> "" then      '-- we know it's an ajax call
       Response.Write(strUserInput)
       Response.End       '-- when doing ajax calls, it's good to add this line so that nothing after this line is sent back to the client
    end if
%>

<script type="text/Javascript">        
    $(document).ready( function(){  
        customFilter();     // you need to call your function on page load for it to do something
        function customFilter() {
            var terms = 'abc';      // what is this line for?
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Test.asp",   << This asp file name
                 data: {strUserInput: '"' + $("#terms").val() + '"'  },   // removed quotes from strUserInput
                 cache: false,
                 success: function( result ) {     // result is just a variable, it can be named anything 
                        alert ( result );
                 }
             });
       }
    });
</script>
```

if nothing still happens, get to know your developers console, in most browsers, you can hit F12 and it'll come up. select the CONSOLE tab (in Chrome) and you'll see any javascript errors if they exist.

good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I modified my code and posted more details code as I am using this logic for autocomplete textbox to retrieve data from database. It does not throw any errors under console but seems like it is not passed the variable strUserInput properly to VB script. The query ignores the selection criteria for strUserInput. Can I use the same ASP code itself for element: URL?